# Search object in CollectionView

Tags: swift

I have Hero Object like this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Hero {

    var name: String!
    var image: UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: "\(name)")!
    }

    required init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

I want to search hero on the search bar, here is my search function:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText:String) {
        let searchBarTemp = searchBar
        heroesFiltered = heroes.filter { (hero) -> Bool in
            if hero.name.lowercaseString == searchBarTemp!.text?.lowercaseString {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }
```

But when I search it's not filtered at all, when I change the text in searchBar, the array is empty.

I also try to search using NSPredicate:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText:String) {
    heroesFiltered = []

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", self.searchBar!.text!)
    let array = (heroes as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    heroesFiltered = array as? [Hero]
}
```

But it crashes at this line:

```
let array = (heroes as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried like this:

```
heroesFiltered = heroes.filter({ (hero) -> Bool in
            let nameText: NSString = hero.name

            return (nameText.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch).location) != NSNotFound
        })
```

And it worked.